# Resizing image in R

Tags: r, image, jpeg

I am trying to work with some image data in R, and cannot figure out how to resize the images I have to ensure they are all the same size.

In Python, I approached this problem as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

size = (100, 100)
img = Image.open(filename)
img = img.resize(size)
img = np.array(img.getdata())
```

In R, I've been unable to locate a library that would accomplish the same thing.
The farthest I've been able to get is:

```
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG(filename)
# Need something here to resize
img <- as.matrix(img)
```

The easiest approach would be a library like Pillow that I could call on, but as I said, I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this with the help of the Bioconductor package **[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/)**, an image processing and analysis toolbox for *R*. To install the package use:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```

You can then use the functionality provided by *EBImage* to load and scale the image, as in the following example.

```
library("EBImage")

x <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))

# width and height of the original image
dim(x)[1:2]

# scale to a specific width and height
y <- resize(x, w = 200, h = 100)

# scale by 50%; the height is determined automatically so that
# the aspect ratio is preserved
y <- resize(x, dim(x)[1]/2)

# show the scaled image
display(y)

# extract the pixel array
z <- imageData(y)

# or
z <- as.array(y)
```

For more examples on the functionality provided by *EBImage* see the the package [vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) .

Answer (score 11):

The package `imager` is a nice fit and hides all the details about splines, interpolations and simply stores the images in a 4 dimensional array (the fourth dimension being used in the case of videos)

```
library(imager)

im <- load.image(my_file)

thmb <- resize(im,round(width(im)/10),round(height(im)/10))

plot(im)
plot(thmb,main="Thumbnail")
```

More informations can be found here: [on the official introduction.](https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html)

Answer (score 8):

Do these options cover what you need:

```
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))

# Set image size in pixels
for (i in 3:6) {
  jpeg(paste0("Pixels",i,".jpeg"), width=200*i, height=200*i)
  plot(as.raster(img))
  dev.off()
}

# Set image size in inches (also need to set resolution in this case)
for (i in 3:6) {
  jpeg(paste0("Inches",i,".jpeg"), width=i, height=i, unit="in", res=600)
  plot(as.raster(img))
  dev.off()
}
```

You can also save in other formats; png, bmp, tiff, pdf. `?jpeg` will display help for saving in bitmap formats. `?pdf` for help on saving as pdf.

Comment: This works for me.  I prefer not to use more libraries than I need to.  One more tip: `par( mar=c(0,0,0,0) )` before the plot line gets rid of unwanted white space.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following code to resample matrices. If you have a jpeg object, you might do that for each color channel individual.

The strategy is as follows:

Given a matrix `m` with the dimensions `a` and `b` and the new dimensions `a.new` and `b.new`

1. Define your new grid

> ```
> x.new <- seq(1,a,length.out=a.new)
> y.new <- seq(1,a,length.out=b.new)
> ```

2. resample the original matrix twice in `x` and in `y` direction

> ```
> V <- apply(V,2,FUN=function(y,x,xout) return(spline(x,y,xout=xout)$y),x,x.new)
> V <- t(apply(V,1,FUN=function(y,x,xout) return(spline(x,y,xout=xout)$y),d,y.new))
> ```

Here I choose the spline-interpolation but you can also use a linear one with `apporx()`. You will gain additionally an x- and y-axis for plotting with the `image(x = x.new, y = y.new, z = V)` function.

Best.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Seily, to resize grey level image.

```
resize = function(img, new_width, new_height) {
  new_img = apply(img, 2, function(y){return (spline(y, n = new_height)$y)})
  new_img = t(apply(new_img, 1, function(y){return (spline(y, n = new_width)$y)}))

  new_img[new_img < 0] = 0
  new_img = round(new_img)

  return (new_img)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With package `imager` and a single parameter

```
library(imager)

im <- load.image(pict)

thmb <- im %>% imresize(0.1)

plot(im)
plot(thmb,main="Thumbnail")
```