# how to convert image to numerical (0-1) pixel matrix in R

Tags: r, image

i found the code to convert the image and got 480*288 numbers of data, because the pixel of the image is that. however, the matrix i want is just much less number matrix like: 19*12 or something. so how can i do that in the R? thanks a lot!.

```
library("EBImage")
img <- readImage("sample.jpg")
img <- channel(img, "grey")
write.csv(t(img), "sample.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code. You get a gray scale 0..1.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the size of the resulting matrix you need to scale the image with `resize` before saving it to a .csv file, see my answer to [Resizing image in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35803260/2792099).

Comment: thanks so much, can u also answer my other question. apperciating