# Resize graph in ggplot - keeping proportions, font size etc

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot, but I managed to make a barplot that I'm pretty happy with. However, I need to make it smaller to fit neatly in a paper. I can't figure out how to resize it without screwing up the proportions, font size etc.
Any ideas?

Here's the plot before resizing:

[image: plot before resizing]

And here it is afterwards, looking horrible:

[image: plot after resizing]

And here is the code I used. Thanks so much!

```
    #creating a data frame

    df <- data.frame("DV"=runif(100), factor1=1:100, factor2=1:100)
    df$factor1[1:50] <- "A"
    df$factor1[51:100] <- "B"
    df$factor2[1:25] <- "X"
    df$factor2[51:75] <- "X"
    df$factor2[26:50] <- "Y"
    df$factor2[76:100] <- "Y"

    plot <- ggplot(df, aes(factor1, DV, fill=factor2)) + 
      stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", position="dodge") +
      stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", 
      position = position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.2) +
      theme_bw()+
      labs(title="Example plot", x="x", y="y", fill="factor2") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=11)) +
      scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("X", "Y"), labels=c("level X", "level Y"), values=c("#D55E00", "#56B4E9")) +
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("A", "B"), labels=c("level A", "levelB")) +
      theme(text=element_text(size=11))
      plot

      ggsave("plot1.eps") #saves a 7x7 image

      ggsave("plot2.eps", height=3.5, width=3.5) #keeping with the dimensions and reducing size, looks horrible
```

Comment: Could you just read in the 7x7 figure you wrote to file and resize it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786744/resizing-image-in-r)?

Comment: That doesn't quite solve it, unfortunately, as I can't control the font size anymore then. And if I also change the aspect ratio, the font even gets distorted. It seems like the easiest solution would be somewhere in defining the size of the image when creating the plot in the first place.